# Rails App Can't highlight any text with mouse

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Have a really strange functionality within one Rails App I'm building where I can't do simple highlight of anything whatsoever. (Meaning clicking with  mouse to highlight text to for example 'copy' the text)  Happening both in development and production.

Tried different browsers and still same issue with this app.  I recognize this is very broad, but anybody run into similar issues that can provide a solution or suggestions?

Running Rails 5.0 on a Macbook.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot copy? Maybe the highlight is just not shown? Overridden by css?

Comment: @Fallenhero Thanks for this.  You're right - the highlight just is showing.  Im searching css rules for this but now getting anything -any ideas?

Comment: @Fallenhero figured it out. You were right.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

CSS overrides specifically for the `:selection` property can create this.  In my situation, it was creating a transparent background so I couldn't see anything being highlighted.  See examples on what to change here: 
https://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/